# How to set an Audience rule value as a Term in powershell?

Tags: powershell, audience-targeting

I am trying to set the condition for an audience rule for example SPS-Location contains a value which is a term value. When I specify the term value as a string in powershell, my audience is not getting compiled and I get an error in compilation message. How to set a term value as a condition in an audience rule in Powershell ?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about Managed Metadata column?

Comment: Yes. A managed metadata column to an audience rule